# Solve a system of differential equations (using integrable combinations method)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system is:

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{y}$

$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{x}$

If we express both equations in terms of $dt$ we get our first solution:

$ \frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{x} = C_1 $

I have hard time figuring out how to find the second one. I know what it equals to
$1 + C_1 x = C_2 * e^{C_1 t}$, 
but have no idea how to get it.

The problem is an exercise meant to practice how to solve DE systems using integrable combinations method. All my attempts to use it (add / substract / divide / multiply both equations of the system) yielded nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are actually supposed to do. But you could note that 
$ \frac1y-\frac1x=C_1$ is equivalent to  $\frac{x}{y}=1+C_1x$. Thus,
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{y} = 1 + C_1 x$$
and you simply have to solve $x'=1+C_1 x$ giving the solution you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$x'=\frac{x}{y}$$ and we get $$y=\frac{x}{x'}$$ thus $$y'=\frac{x'^2-x\cdot x''}{x'^2}$$ and we get the equation
$$\frac{x^2-xx''}{x'^2}=\frac{1}{x'}$$ and we have to solve
$$x'^2-xx''=x'$$

Comment: which is not correct as far as I can see it.

Comment: then Show me the mistake please!

Comment: ok it was a typo,$$x'^2-xx''=x'$$